# Reset gitlab user password via UI

Tags: gitlab

How to reset GitLab user password of a normal user via UI ?
(Via command line it is possible using rake)
We are using an on-premise GitLab community edition

Comment: Do you mean as an administrator for another user? Or for yourself?

Answer (score 3):

To change/reset your own GitLab user password: see [change your password](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/#change-your-password)

As a GitLab administrator, to (re)set another user's password in the UI:

1. Navigate to **Admin Area -> Users**
2. Locate the user whose password you want to reset
3. Click "edit"
4. Enter new password (and again in confirmation field)
5. Click "save"

As you mentioned, you can also use [a rake task or rails console](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/reset_user_password.html).